# loop through a column and pull out specific cells

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a spreadsheet with a bunch of data all in one column and I'm looking to pull out specific data. I'm trying to see if a 'do until loop' will work.

I'm trying to get the loop to stop when it see "directory*" as part of the cell for example Directory of G:\Example. Until then the loop should look through the Cells and if it doesn't start with a number copy that cell to another sheet/column.

```
Sub Order()

iRow = 1

  Do Until Cells(iRow, 1) = "Directory*"
   If Cells(iRow, 1) <> NumberatBeginning Then
    Cells(iRow, 1).Copy _
    Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
   End If


   iRow = iRow + 1
  Loop

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, the `IsNumeric` function can be used in conjunction with the `Mid` (or `Left`) function to check the first character in the cell value and return `True` or `False` if the character is numeric. Try this:

```
Sub Order()

Dim iRow as Long, x as Long

iRow = 1
x = 1

Do Until Cells(iRow, 1).Value Like "Directory*"
    If Not IsNumeric(Mid(Cells(iRow, 1).Value, 1, 1)) Then
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(x, 1).Value = Cells(iRow, 1).Value
        x = x + 1
    End If
iRow = iRow + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

You should avoid using copy and paste as it slows down code, it is always better to simply set the value of the cell.

Also, when you're looping through and copying the cells with non-numeric first characters and pasting them into `Sheet2` your code is always pasting into the same cell, `Range("A1")`, assuming you want a list of the values you will need to increment this by adding a row each time a value is copied to `Sheet2`.

Comment: Surely `Like "Directory*"` would be false if there was a number at the start so no need to test for that anyway?

Comment: But @OP wants the loop to stop when it finds a value that begins with `"Directory*"` or so I understood from the question